# C# Not getting all properties from GetProperties

Tags: c#, foreach, getproperties

I'm going around in cricles changing and rechanging not understanding why I'm not getting the values I want to, maybe someone can shed some light on it.

I have this object

```
var result = new GetRatePlanListResponse
        {
            RatePlanId = prodRpsResult.Id,
            RatePlanName = prodRpsResult.Name,
            EffectiveStartDate = prodRpsResult.EffectiveStartDate,
            EffectiveEndDate = prodRpsResult.EffectiveEndDate,
            BillingPeriod = prodRpsResult.PRDP_BillingFrequency__c.HasValue ? prodRpsResult.PRDP_BillingFrequency__c.Value.ToString() : null,
            ShippingSchedule = prodRpsResult.PRDP_DeliveryFrequency__c.HasValue ? prodRpsResult.PRDP_DeliveryFrequency__c.Value.ToString() : null,
            UsageLevel = prodRpsResult?.PRDP_UsageLevel__c,
            IncludedUnits = prodRpsResult?.PRDP_NumberofPackages__c,
            BasePrice = new RatePlanBasePrice
            {
                Currency = pricing != null ? pricing.Currency : string.Empty,
                Price = pricing != null && pricing.Price != null ? pricing.Price.Value : 0
            }
        };
```

Then I call this fucntion with that object has argument:

```
    public void PriceConverter<T>(ref T obj)
    {
        Type t = obj.GetType();

        foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties())
        {
            if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(RootPrices)).Any(x => x.ToLower() == prop.Name.ToLower()))
            {
                prop.SetValue(obj, ((int)(double.Parse((string)prop.GetValue(obj)) * 100)).ToString(), null);
            }
            
        }

    }
```

My problem is that for some reason I can't access the values Currency and Price. how can I do that?

EDIT:

Ok, guys thanks for the info,, I decided to change my approach since I can't get a way to change a generic object property if they have other objects inside since they respresent a different reference. Although I'm changing it I would appreciate if someone know a way to recursivly or iteratively change a referenced object and all the object it references and can provide a solution it would help me out in the future when I'm given a task to transform multiple objects data of pre-existing code base which have similar fields.

Comment: `Currency` and `Price` aren't properties on the passed-in object.  You get those from the object referenced by the `BasePrice` variable.

Comment: You're saying that they are poperties of BasePrice? If so how can I get all porperties and sub-properties how should I change my cycle? @Amy

Comment: IMO, I don't think reflection should be used. I don't see what its gaining you, here.

Comment: I want to do a method that receives an object and can iterate through all properties (subProperties) and match them with a list so if a converstion needs to be done it will authomatically change it's a value. So I can call it passing the object as reference, instead of having to go through all the objects and manually transform the data. If you have a better suggestion It's appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Both `Currency` and `Price` belongs to `RatePlanBasePrice` type not to `GetRatePlanListResponse`.
So, you have to obtain `BasePrice` property first. If `RatePlanBasePrice` is a *class* (not *struct*):

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Reflection;

  ...  

  var prop = obj
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => 
      string.Equals("BasePrice", p.PropertyType) &&
      p.CanRead &&
      typeof(RatePlanBasePrice).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

  if (prop != null) {
    obj val = prop.GetValue(obj);

    if (val != null) {
      RatePlanBasePrice value = (RatePlanBasePrice) val;

      // Put relevant code here 
      val.Currency = ...
      val.Price = ...
    }
  }
```

If If `RatePlanBasePrice` is a *struct*:

```
  var prop = obj
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => 
      string.Equals("BasePrice", p.PropertyType) &&
      p.CanRead && 
      p.CanWrite &&
      typeof(RatePlanBasePrice).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

  if (prop != null) {
    // uncomment, if you need an old value  
    //var oldValue = (RatePlanBasePrice) (prop.GetValue(obj));

    prop.SetValue(obj, new RatePlanBasePrice() {
      // Put relevant code here
      Currency = ...
      Price = ... 
    });
  }
```

**Edit:** Yes, you can loop over properties, but why? If you use *Linq*, it's quite natural to put a single query.
If you are looking for some kind of *generic case*, let's extract a method:

```
private static bool TryReadProperty<T>(object source, string name, out T value) {
  value = default(T);

  if (null == source)
    return false;

  var prop = source
    .GetType()
    .GetProperties()
    .FirstOrDefault(p => string.Equals(p.Name, name) &&
                         p.CanRead &&
                         typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

  if (null == prop)
    return false;

  value = (T) (prop.GetValue(prop.GetGetMethod().IsStatic ? null : source));

  return true;
}
```

then you can use it

```
if (TryGetProperty<RatePlanBasePrice>(obj, "BasePrice", out var value)) {
  // Put relevant code here 
  val.Currency = ...
  val.Price = ...
}
```

Comment: Would there be a way to maintain the the loop, and understand that BasePrice is a complex type and call the function passing it that object? Do I need to use typeof(RatePlanBasePrice) or is there a generic way to do it? Or it can't be done?

Comment: You're right, using linq you can query I'll try use your code to see if I can achieve what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could just call `PriceConverter<T>` recursively on the value of each `property` in `t`. You will need to implement some sort of filtering if you don't want to call `PriceConverter<T>` on properties of a specific type.

For the simple example you've given, you might be able to get away with only getting readable, mutable properties. Also, it doesn't look like the `ref` keyword is necessary since you're potentially mutating properties of `obj`, but not actually changing the reference.

```
void PriceConverter<T>(T obj)
{
    Type t = obj.GetType();
    foreach (var prop in t.GetProperties().Where(p => p.CanRead && p.CanWrite))
    {
        object value = prop.GetValue(obj);
        if (value != null)
        {
            PriceConverter(value);
        }

        if (Enum.GetNames(typeof(RootPrice)).Any(x => x.ToLower() == prop.Name.ToLower()))
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, ((int)(double.Parse((string)prop.GetValue(obj)) * 100)).ToString(), null);
        }
    }
    
}
```